# How to protect redirecting urls on my site and stop inappropriate usage of it by external sites?

Tags: php, redirect

I have redirecting urls on my site like:

```
__http://example.com/jump?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsome-external-site.com%2Fsome-page.html
```

When I input into search bar at google site this phrase:

```
site:http://example.com
```

I see that google have indexed inappropriate content from that external sites (from redirecting urls) and treat it as pages from my site (which isn't really placed on my site). Someone take my redirecting urls, genereted with them own urls and force google to index that redirecting urls with external pages with inappropriate content.

What should I do in such case? How to protect my redirecting urls from such inappropriate usage?

I am using php for redirecting.

Comment: Setting a link to any reachable site in the web is allowed to anyone. You can't prohibit the usage of links. And that is good. You can however control the links people use to reach targets on your page (e.g. paywall, control robots, access-control, ...). If you don't want that others get the links you have placed on your page to reach others just control the way they can read your links ...

Comment: @Melvin, I was thinking about some kind of tokens to put into my redirect urls to prevent external generating of my redirecting urls. Is it a good idea? Do you know how do this popular sites? Thank you for reply!

Comment: Well - what I've done on some of my pages is to use a landing-page, give it a token and it redirects you to a new target on my page. That way the search-engine won't get the clear URL. But it hurts SEO (engines don't like redirects). And most of all if a human follows the redirect, the page will be clear and can be used as well. 

Finally, if you generate an external link you need a working URL which can be viewed. The http/https-protocol is nothing magical and targets are in plain sight when your browser is able to show them. I didn't stumble on a page which was able to hide the origins.

Comment: @Melvin, facebook doesn't use redirect urls as well as google and stackoverflow. They use "rel=nofollow". Twitter uses t.co domain for redirection urls. So I am asking myself if I need that redirection urls now.

Comment: "rel=nofollow" Is just a tag for robots not to add the following site but anyone can click the link, follow to the site and copy the link to use it as his own. Your start-problem was that others use your link - you can't protect yourself with nofollow.
The t.co is just a short-cut. Whenever anyone calls the shortcut, moves to the new site and gets the normal link which can be used again. The only protection would be if a browser wouldn't show the link - but they all do sooner or later. You get the new URL - even out of the protocol-data you can extract the URL.